# Laravel 5.5 password reset token form not appearing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.5 project, I received the following after submitting email id from password reset form:

> http://localhost/administrator/password/reset?41704c353d33830724d76eefa0702b47201d60fe9957552fdf96e29d7c2cc62a

However, when pasting the above URL in browser, the 'laravel log' said that "local.INFO: Unable to find page". And I see that email submission form is displayed instead of the password & confirm password form.

My **routes** is defined as follows:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'administrator'], function() {
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.email');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset.token');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.reset');
});
```

My ResetPasswordController.php as follows;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Model\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Hash;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/administrator/password/reset';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


     /**
     * METHOD TO RESET ADMIN PASSWORD
     */

}
```

Comment: make sure you dont have `Auth::routes()` in your routes

Comment: No I don't have this.

Comment: have you resolved? I've the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust the routes according.

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'administrator'], function() {

    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset.token');
    Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.email');
    Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');

    Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.reset');
    });
```

Move your `password/reset/{token}` above the `password/reset`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there anything I need to write in auth controller?

Comment: post your controller too

Comment: `public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }` remove this line

Comment: anything else ?